# A symmetric, diagonally dominant matrix A with real positive diagonal entries is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric and diagonally dominant with positive diagonal entries. I have to prove that $A$ is positive definite but without using theorems, just algebraically.

I´ve started with: $$x^T A x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} x_i^2 + \sum_{i=j} a_{ij} x_i x_j > \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j} |a_{ij}| x_i^2 + \sum_{i\neq j} a_{ij} x_i x_j$$ but I could much further. I was thiking about: $$ \sum_{1=1}^n \sum_{j>i} |a_{ij}| (x_i^2 + x_j^2) + 2 a_{ij} x_i x_j$$ but I´m not sure how to continue.

Comment: Doesn't positive definite enclose symmetric? Hence, can't you just write down a non-symmetric matrix which satisfies your assumptions?

Comment: @Klaus In some circles, a real matrix is said to be positive definite if and only if $x^TAx > 0$ for all real vectors $x$, which is equivalent to the condition that the symmetric matrix $A + A^T$ is "symmetric and" positive definite.

Comment: @Klaus it was my mistake, A is SYMMETRIC and diagonally dominant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you write $x^TAx=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,i}x_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}a_{i,j}x_ix_j\ge\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{i,j}|)x_i^2-\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{i,j}||x_i||x_j| =\sum_{j>i }(|a_{i,j}|(x_i^2+x_j^2-2|x_i||x_j|))\ge 0$

Comment: Sorry, can I ask what does "diagonally dominant with positive diagonal entries" mean?

Comment: Positive diagonal entries means that each $a_{ii} > 0$. That is, all elements on the diagonal are positive. Diagonally dominant means $|a_{ii}| \geq \sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}| \ \text{for all } i$. That is, for each row, the magnitude of the diagonal element on that row is bigger than the sum of magnitudes of all other elements.