# If the diagonal entries are real and positive, is the matrix positive-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, is a hermitian matrix with guaranteed real and positive diagonal entries. Also $\det(A)>0$. Is $A$ positive-definite?

Positive-definite matrices have real and positive diagonal entries, but I have not found any resource whether the converse is true or not. I know that this is true in case of eigenvalues, but I wish not to calculate eigenvalues. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435631/a-symmetric-diagonally-dominant-matrix-a-with-real-positive-diagonal-entries-is) solves it for a real matrix and I was wondering if the same can be done for complex matrix?

Comment: in that case $A=I + B B^H$ is positive definite, because $B B^H$ is positive semidefinite, and $I$  is positive definite.

Comment: @orangeskid thanks so much. I should have properly explained in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The linked question only solves it for diagonally dominant matrices, and the same argument made there could be made for diagonally dominant *complex* matrices.

---

In general, the answer to your question is no, even for real matrices. For example, the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-3 &&-3\\ -3 &1&&2\\-3&&2&&1\end{bmatrix}$$ has two negative eigenvalues and one positive eigenvalue.

Note, of course, that the matrix I provide is *not* diagonally dominant.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand. What else can be done for checking whether $A$ is positive-definite or not?

Comment: @titusarmah99 The easiest way to show a matrix is positive definite is to calculate its Cholesky decomposition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: In my case, $A$ is calculated as $A=BB^H$ where $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$. How will it make sense to find Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: Sorry, it is $A=I_n + BB^H$ where $I_n$ is identity matrix.

Comment: @titusarmah99 A sum of positive definite matrices is positive definite.