# Cholesky decomposition of a strictly diagonaly dominant symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

I am studying for a exam and I thought about practicing the Cholesky decomposition.

If a matrix $A = A^{T}$ , the main diagonal of $A$ has only positive elements and in every row the absolute value of the element in the main diagonal $>$ the sum of the absolute values of the other elements in the same row then we can decompose $A$ to $U^{T}U$ where $U$ is a upper matrix.Well I tried solving a example on my own:

[image]

and then decide to check its validity by putting it in the [Symbolab matrix calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-calculator/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D2%26-1%260%5C%5C%20%20-1%263%261%5C%5C%20%200%261%264%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Dx_%7B1%7D%5C%5C%20%20x_%7B2%7D%5C%5C%20%20x_%7B3%7D%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%3D%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%5C%5C%20%201%5C%5C%20%201%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D?or=input) but I dont get the same results.

Help appreciated!

Comment: There is a term for the property "in every row the absolute value of the element in the main diagonal > the sum of the absolute values of the other elements in the same row" which is:  "strictly diagonally dominant"

Answer (score 1):

Click on this link: [A symmetric, diagonally dominant matrix A with real positive diagonal entries is positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3435631/305862).

This property shows that such a matrix possesses a Cholesky decomposition $U^TU$ with $U$ upper triangular.

---

**Edit:** I have spotted the error in your particular example: the constraint $bc+ed=0$ (coming from line 3 times column 2) should be $bc+ed=\color{red}{1}$.

Comment: Any comment ?...